# How to generate code cells in google colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is it possible to generate code cells in google colab with a given text? A code that creates more code?

Something like:

```
create_cell("print('Hello world')")
```

So the result would be another cell with the code `print('Hello world')`.

Comment: Any luck finding an answer?